# MySQL: ERROR 1064?

Tags: mysql

I created a table using those commands:

```
use users;
create table users(
userid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
pass VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
jobfunction VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);
```

then I tried to insert new user using this command:

```
insert into users (username, pass, firstname, lastname) (‘admin’, ‘0000’, ‘foo’, ‘bar’);
```

the insert command wasn't working for me unfortuantly, because of a syntax error code 1064 was output by mysql.
so why I'm getting this error? and how to fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use single-quotes or double-quotes around your string values, not smart quotes.

Also you are missing the `VALUES` keyword:

```
insert into users (username, pass, firstname, lastname) 
values ('admin', '0000', 'foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: The query I pasted above should work. What is the error message?

Comment: the problem was caused by the smart quotes, I changed it to single quotes and that solved the problem! thanks.

Comment: Better use single-quotes. Double quotes for string values are non-standard and won't work on other (ANSI compliant) DBMS